# get location in android phone with Pusher

Tags: javascript, java, android, gps, pusher

I plan to make a simple android app that will get the location using android GPS. The problem here is that, I want to know  if it is possible to send location to server when Pusher send a message to all clients in a channel and the app of clients are in background.

So scenario example,
A browser client send a request to server. Then the server send the message to Pusher channel. All android app clients that is subscribed to the channel will receive a push notification then it will get the client's location. It will be sent to the server.

I tried to create a step by step guide to how to create this.
Here is what I created,
1.) The app is opened, then it will subscribe to the channel.
2.) Even in background it must be subscribed to the channel.
3.) Run a method when a new message from the channel received.
3.) Then use LocationService to run the location gps in background.
4.) Send the location to the server.

Is this possible? Can anyone give a step by step guide to help me develop this app? Is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: Look at this if you want to stick with Pusher for handling your push notifications. https://pusher.com/docs/push_notifications

Comment: This page provide information on how it sends notifications to each mobile phones. But it didn't provide information if I can use this to get location of each mobile phones.

Comment: When your phone gets a notification, you can use the Android Location API to get the location and send to your server

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer. I will try that.